# Android: register app as file picker

Tags: android

I would like to register my app as Android app system for the selection of files (like Dropbox).

Basically when the user is, for example, on a web page in the browser and press the html button "Browse ..." the operating system should show the available options (system gallery, GDrive, Dropbox, etc.) and also my app. Once you select the file (in this case CSV) should be returned to the field in the file browser and and processed as a normal file.

how can I register the app as file picker and how can I return the file to the app caller?

Thanks

Comment: look for intent and intemt filters in android

Answer (score 2):

You need in your Manifest.xml define [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) for your Activity like this:

```
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/pick_file">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Where's "mime-type" is your file extension, that you want to choose. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#DataTest).

Comment: Great! now I can see it in the application file selection. What I can not do though is give back the file. How can I return the file to the main application? I have to return the path?

Comment: Yes, you can return a path to a file, and then open it. You can return it value by using [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).